# Check if ARSession is running (ARKit)

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, arscnview

I have an ARSCNView that can occasionally pause its `session` depending on the situation. Is there a way to check if its `session` is running?

Something like this:

```
class myARView: ARSCNView {
    ...
    func foo() {

        if(session.running) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: One way would be to set a boolean whenever you pause/resume the session and check that boolean in your function.

Comment: Right, I thought about that but the ARSCNView is exposed so if I/someone else forget(s) to set that boolean or use the custom start/pause methods it could result in unwanted behavior. If there is no built-in way though then post it as answer, I will accept. If you do so please also mention the absence of this API :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if there's really no way to achieve this using the API, I'm checking it right now. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this moment, it seems there isn't a way to check if the session is running, by [ARSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession) object itself. However, by implementing `ARSCNViewDelegate`, you can get notified whenever your session is interrupted or the interruption ends.

One way to achieve your goal is to set a boolean and update it whenever you pause/resume the session, and check its value in your functions.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    var isSessionRunning: Bool

    func foo() {
        if self.isSessionRunning {
            // do stuff
        }
    }

    func pauseSession() {
        self.sceneView.session.pause()
        self.isSessionRunning = false
    }

    func runSession() {
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
        self.isSessionRunning = true
    }

    // ARSCNViewDelegate:
    func sessionWasInterrupted(_ session: ARSession) {
        self.isSessionRunning = false
    }

    func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ session: ARSession) {
        self.isSessionRunning = true
    }
}
```

Comment: ok so when trying to reproduce this, I found out that `session.pause()` doesn't pause anything at all and also that I forgot to mention I was trying to use that function :D. Since dear Apple has forgotten pausing the scene when pause() is called, using a boolean and keeping track of it as you said seems to be the only reliable way (I tried it just now, I can confirm that after calling this ARSession's stupid built-in `session.pause()` function, my device was still tracking motion).

Comment: To clarify, question was not on how to pause, but what I meant is that you answer solves both the tracking (as asked), and when trying it I also figured the boolean is necessary even when not tracking the state because `session.pause()` doesn't even work anyways